# I get Fatal Exception using multiple OnClickListeners

Tags: java, android, fatal-error

The Main thing happens in FATAL EXECEPTION my App don't Launches and error comes unfortunately stopped it keeps crashing 
Tried switch case and else if still the error continues the app keeps crashing 
Googled and search over stackflow the different usersover stackflowed faced this error still the error continues with me even after trying their solution with single if and single onclicklistener app manages to run but not with multiple onlicklistener is there a different way to run multiple onclick listener app please help me

here's MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.cricscore;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

// Private member field to keep track of the count 
private int mCount = 0; 
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity"; 


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


    Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
    buttonA.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    Button buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
    buttonB.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
 }

   public void onClick(View v) {
       try {
        switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button1: 
               mCount++; 
               final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               countTextView.setText(""+ mCount); 
            break;
           case R.id.button2:
               mCount= mCount+2 ; 
               final TextView countTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               countTextView1.setText(""+ mCount);
            break;


        }
       }
       catch(Throwable t) {
           Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage(), t);

       }

   }
 }
```

And the Activity_main.xml is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Runs" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:text="Wickets" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:text="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:text="6" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Wicket" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button5"
    android:text="Balls" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button7"
    android:text="4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView7"
    android:text="No/Wide" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button5"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button8"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      
    activity
  ComponentInfo{com.example.abc/com.example.abc.MainActivity}:  java.lang.ClassCastException:    
  com.example.abc.MainActivity
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at     
  android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at   
  android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:1663)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500
  (ActivityThread.java:117)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage 
  (ActivityThread.java:931)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage 
  (Handler.java:99)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main 
  (ActivityThread.java:3683)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native  
  Method)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke 
  (Method.java:507)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at  
  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main 
  (ZygoteInit.java:597)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:  
  com.example.abc.MainActivity
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at com.example.abc.MainActivity.onCreate 
  (MainActivity.java:30)
  03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):    at   
  android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):   at  
   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
   03-18 14:09:37.717: E/AndroidRuntime(360):   ... 11 more
```

After Some Modification As told by the 1st answer my code didn't crashed but I was only able to see blank activity where android_mainfest is still the same

```
package com.example.cricscore;

import android.app.Activity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.View.OnClickListener; 
import android.widget.Button; 
import android.widget.TextView; 

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener { 

// Private member field to keep track of the count 
private int mCount = 0; 
/** Called when the activity is first created. 
 * @param OnClickListener */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, android.view.View.OnClickListener 
OnClickListener){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


    Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
    buttonA.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) );
    Button buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
    buttonB.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) );
 }

   public void OnClickListener(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button1: 
               mCount++; 
               final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               countTextView.setText(""+ mCount); 
            break;
           case R.id.button2:
               mCount= mCount+2 ; 
               final TextView countTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               countTextView1.setText(""+ mCount);
            break;


        }


   }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 }
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It's much easier to get help if you manage to cut your problem to it's root causes. Avoid pasting large amounts of code, as that only makes it harder for people to spot your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) method expects a parameter of type [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html). What you are doing is taking the [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) itself, and trying to coerce it being a  `OnClickListener` which it is not, in this piece of code:

```
Button buttonA = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);    
buttonA.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this); // <-- here
Button buttonB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
buttonB.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this); // <-- and here too
```

You should declare your activity to be an OnClickListener, using:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

and as you already have a `onClick(View v)` method, the problem should be fixed.

Comment: even after adding 
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener

Still I'm getting Java Fatal Error 
App crashes